# Why does "cp -r a/. b" behave as it does?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cp

I thought that `a` and `a/.` is the same path. However, I've found that *cp* and *rsync* copy directory content instead of directory itself when `/.` is added to the source path. I also tried `a/inner/..`; this did the trick as well.

```
$ cp -r a b  # Copies dir a into dir b.
$ cp -r a/. b  # Copies files from dir a into dir b.
$ cp -r a/inner/.. b  # Also copies files from dir a into dir b.
$ cd a && cp -r . ../b  # One more way to copy inner files.
```

I understand that this is useful. But I'm a bit confused because it seems this feature breaks standards.

How does this work? Is this feature documented somewhere? Is this a feature of the OS, *cp* or bash?

Comment: `cp a b` doesn't copy a directory called "a" to a new directory called "b" in Ubuntu.  It outputs `cp: omitting directory 'a'` and does nothing.  You have to use the `-r` option (or something that implies it, such as `-a`) to copy directories.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed the `-r` option in examples, but I use it on real task. Fixed. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that this is useful. But I'm a bit confused because it seems this feature breaks standards.

*cp* behavior when copying recursively from `a/.` to `b` is perfectly consistent with its "normal" behavior.

By default, *cp*'s doesn't create parent directories. This can be modified with the *parents* switch:

```
   --parents
          use full source file name under DIRECTORY
```

But what does that mean?

It means that while the command

```
cp --parents -r some/path/to/source dest
```

will copy the source directory's contents into `dest/some/path/to/source`, the command

```
cp -r some/path/to/source dest
```

will copy the source directory's contents into `dest/source`.

Likewise, the command

```
cp -r some/path/to/source/. dest
```

will copy the source directory's contents into `dest/.`, which is just `dest`.

> I thought `a` and `a/.` is the same path.

`a` and `a/.` *is* the same path. But as an argument to *cp*, it is just a string.

Note that the commands

```
cp --parents -r some/path/to/source dest
```

and

```
cd some/path/to && cp --parents -r source dest
```

will behave differently as well.

---

> What about `cp -r a/inner/.. b`? Taking into account your explanation, should not it copy files to `b/..` (i.e. to the current directory)?

Well, yes. This is an exception.

At least in the GNU version of *cp*, there is a special case for for the `..` basename.

From [`coreutils-8.22/src/cp.c`](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/):

```
          if (parents_option)
            {
              [removed]
            }
          else
            {
              char *arg_base;
              /* Append the last component of 'arg' to 'target_directory'.  */

              ASSIGN_BASENAME_STRDUPA (arg_base, arg);
              /* For 'cp -R source/.. dest', don't copy into 'dest/..'. */
              dst_name = (STREQ (arg_base, "..")
                          ? xstrdup (target_directory)
                          : file_name_concat (target_directory, arg_base,
                                              NULL));
            }
```

The motivation seems to be to avoid copying outside the destination folder, which – while perfectly consistent with *cp*'s behavior in every other case – is a little counterintuitive and could have unpleasant consequences.

After all, I don't think anybody would expect the command

```
cp -r .. ~
```

to affect files outside his home directory...

Comment: Brilliant! But what about `cp -r a/inner/.. b`? Taking into account your explanation, should not it copy files to `b/..` (i.e. to the current directory)?

Comment: @raacer: I've updated by answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ mkdir a b a/inner
$ touch a/a{1..3} b/b{1..3}
$ ls -R
.:
a  b

./a:
a1  a2  a3  inner

./a/inner:

./b:
b1  b2  b3
$ cp a b
cp: omitting directory ‘a’
$ cp a/. b
cp: omitting directory ‘a/.’
$ cp a/inner/.. b
cp: omitting directory ‘a/inner/..’
$ cd a && cp . ../b
cp: omitting directory ‘.’
$ cd ..
$ ls -R
.:
a  b

./a:
a1  a2  a3  inner

./a/inner:

./b:
b1  b2  b3
```

None of the things you say happen, actually happen. The four `cp` commands do nothing. Perhaps you have an alias for `cp` loaded. You can check this with `alias cp`.

Comment: Better yet, `which cp` should tell the full story. This might be some convenience version/version with training wheels provided by OP's distribution.

Comment: `cp -r` behaves like stated in the question.

Comment: I just missed the `-r` option in my examples. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: @raacer: No problems. My guess was that you actually had `alias cp='cp -r'` set, but this explains it as well :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Apropos `rsync(1)`, read its manual *carefully*. It uses some unusual conventions to mean "the contents of the directory" vs "the directory and its contents."

For `cp(1)` and other Linux commands, at the *kernel* level `a` and `a/.` and even `a/inner/..` refer to the exact same directory. That doesn't mean the application can't parse them for itself and give them funky different meanings, but it is easier to just ship the string to the kernel, who will do the right thing.

Comment: I thought so too about cp. Dennis provided some useful explanation how this actually works.

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly I believe the . in this instance works similar to an *. In essence, a wildcard character.

Comment: It seems this is not true. `*` is a shell feature. Bash'es manual says nothing about `.` in the Pathname Expansion section. You can ensure that dot is not a part of standard path expansion by comparing the result of `stat ./*` and `stat ./.`. So while it gives us same result with cp, this is not really same, and probably **works** different way. Just the **result** is similar.

Comment: Is it possible that it's using . as a wildcard from some regex implementations?